# Guardar variable "user_pass" en WordPress y luego llamarla

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una duda con respecto a la variable "user_pass", la cual contiene momentáneamente la contraseña sin encriptar del usuario que se registra. La cual estoy viendo en está [página del codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/). Quiero guardar esa contraseña sin encriptar en la base de datos y luego llamarla desde una función, pero no sé muy bien como hacerlo.

Muestra de código (línea 1420):

```
// hashed in wp_update_user(), plaintext if called directly
    $user_pass = ! empty( $userdata['user_pass'] ) ? $userdata['user_pass'] : $old_user_data->user_pass;
} else {
    $update = false;
    // Hash the password
    $user_pass = wp_hash_password( $userdata['user_pass'] );
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: La variable se obtiene aquí: `$userdata['user_pass']`. Si la quieres guardar en otra variable: `$no_encriptada=$userdata['user_pass']; ` Si quieres retornarla, simplemente escribes al final de la función, antes de cerrarla: `function tu_funcion () {      $user_pass = ! empty( $userdata['user_pass'] ) ? $userdata['user_pass'] : $old_user_data->user_pass; $no_encriptada=$userdata['user_pass']; 
    return $no_encriptada;.... }`

Comment: Gracias el código es muy claro. pero sabes si puedo guardarla en una nueva tabla y luego llamarla según el ID del usuario.

Comment: Estuve investigando y lo más recomendable es enviar esa variable en el momento. Guardar la variable en una tabla es más tedioso y crea agujeros de seguridad. Ahora estoy modificando mi función y agregando tu ejemplo.

Comment: En realidad no sé para que quieres recuperar ese dato **antes de encriptarlo**, WP lo encripta y lo guarda encriptado porque es  un dato importante. Si ves la documentación verás que el dato se guarda encriptado y se puede desencriptar si lo necesitas para algo. Aunque esa clase de datos no suelen ser manipulados, salvo en un entorno seguro, protegido por contraseña y si es posible usando el protocolo `https://...`

Comment: Es que necesito gatillar todos los datos del usuario en una URL para registrarlo en otro sitio web con ASP.net. Esa fue la forma en que me dijo el otro informático a cargo de la otra web. Son ordenes superiores, así que debo acatarlas aunque no me me convenza mucho la idea.

Comment: _gatillar todos los datos del usuario en una URL_ ¿Te refieres a mandar los datos, clave incluida, por una URL? Si es eso, ¿por qué no tomarlos directamente de la base de datos? Puedes conectarte perfectamente a la BD teniendo los permisos necesarios, claro está, y obtener los datos sin tener que enviarlos por una URL. Es mucho más seguro. Saludos.

Comment: Es que tiene que ser automático y la contraseña esta encriptada en la base de datos y no se como desencriptarla, además no obtuve mucha información de como gatillar y desencriptar los datos en un trigger con PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Al final me función ha quedado de está manera:

```html
//ENVIAR DATOS DE NUEVOS USUARIOS REGISTRADOS AL SISTEMA DE ABSTRACTS EXTERNO
function shapeSpace_register_add_meta($user_id) { //Verificar el inicio de sesión por primera vez de un usuario
 add_user_meta($user_id, '_new_user', '1');
}
add_action('user_register', 'shapeSpace_register_add_meta');

function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) { //Comprobar si el usuario inicia sesión por primera vez
 $new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
 if ($new_user) {
  update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  $titulo = $current_user->title;
  $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname;
  $apellido = $current_user->user_lastname;
  $institucion = $current_user->institution;
  $direccion = $current_user->addr1;
  $ciudad = $current_user->city;
  $pais = $current_user->country;
  $correo = $current_user->user_email;
  $correo_anterior = $correo;

  //Obtener contraseña antes de que sea encriptada

        $user_pass = ! empty($userdata['user_pass']) ?
        $userdata['user_pass'] : $old_user_data->user_pass;
        $pass_no_encriptada = $userdata['user_pass'];

        //Comprobar campos que pueden estar vacíos

  if (empty($titulo)) {
    $titulo = "Mr";
  }

  if (empty($institucion)) {
    $institucion = "Unknown institution";
  }

  if (empty($ciudad)) {
    $ciudad = "Unknown city";
  }

        //Creación de las URL con datos del usuario

  $url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .$pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$pass_no_encriptada. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior;
  $url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$pass_no_encriptada;

  //Gatillar las URL

        shell_exec($url_registro);
        shell_exec($url_acceso);

 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
```

Ahora sólo debo testearla.

Answer (score 0):

recomiendo que pongas tu funcion como sigue:

```
function shapeSpace_register_add_meta($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_pass'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass_plano', $_POST['user_pass']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'shapeSpace_register_add_meta');
```

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia, pero ¿la variable user_pass_plano a dónde va?

Comment: "user_pass_plano" será un matadato de usuario que estara guardado en la tabla wp_usermeta, este lo pusedes tomar en cualqueir archivos PHP con la instrucción: get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass_plano', true);